# I can't install "ruby-odbc" in IronRuby

Tags: ironruby

I want to connect to MS Sql server in IronRuby, and I have install "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.4)", "dbd-odbc (0.2.4)","dbi (0.4.2)", and seems that I have to install "ruby-odbc", but I don't know why can't install it.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-odbc:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

E:/ironruby-1.0v4/bin/ir.exe extconf.rb
can't find header files for ruby.

Gem files will remain installed in E:/ironruby-1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-odbc-0.99993 for inspection.
Results logged to E:/ironruby-1.0v4/lib/ironruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-odbc-0.99993/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

ruby-odbc uses some native code and IronRuby doesn't support native gems.

You can use activerecord-sqlserver-adapter with ADO.NET as the backend. See https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Sam, I was able to get ruby-odbc working on Windows 7.  I wrote a blog post on how I got rails 3 up and running on windows 7.  It includes a couple of steps that helped me get ruby-odbc working on windows.  Here's the link: [Getting Rails 3 Up on Windows Connecting to SQL Server](http://rob-rowe.blogspot.com/2010/10/getting-rails-3-up-on-windows.html)